# Concurrently write results to SQLite database

Tags: python, concurrency, sqlite

The goal is to run a function `compute` in parallel on many inputs (`10**6` in total, say) and store the results.
Each call to `compute` takes a few seconds and is independent of other `compute`s.

Since running it on all inputs takes too long (even on many cores), I want to be able to start computing, interrupt it, and continue later without redoing any computations.

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265148/13087987) for the WAL setting and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30816116/13087987) to give each process a db connection.

I don't have a great understanding of what's going on under the hood in `multiprocessing` or `sqlite3` (let alone their combination with WAL) - I'd be curious to get some intuition what might become a problem at different scales. E.g. when the number of parallel processes grows, do they have to wait longer and longer for a lock to become available, or can they submit their db transaction and move to the next computation?

**EDIT:** there seems to be a problem with the approach below: when `pool.map` finishes, it leaves behind a `results.db-wal` file with results that are not written into `results.db`.
I had to insert a manual WAL checkpoint (`connection.execute(f"PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(PASSIVE);")`
after `pool.map` to get all results written in the db.

```
import sqlite3
import multiprocessing

def compute(x):
    return 2*x

db = 'results.db'
reset_db = True  # set to False to continue earlier run

def reset(file):
    con = sqlite3.connect(file)
    try:
        con.execute("DROP TABLE results")
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        pass
    con.execute("CREATE TABLE results(input UNIQUE, output)")
    con.close()

def init_worker(function):
    function.con = sqlite3.connect(db)
    function.con.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL")

def already_present(con, param):
    return bool(con.execute("SELECT 1 FROM results WHERE input=?", (param, )).fetchone())

def write_result(con, param, result):
    with con:
        con.execute("INSERT INTO results VALUES (?, ?)", (param, results,))

def check_compute_and_write(param):
    if already_present(check_compute_and_write.con, param):
        return
    result = compute(param)
    write_result(check_compute_and_write.con, param, result)

if reset_db:
    reset(db)

with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(check_compute_and_write,)) as pool:
    pool.map(check_compute_and_write, range(10**6))
```

Comment: Consider having your N workers append results to N .csv text files, or to a unified lockf()-controlled text file. And then periodically a single writer will gather and INSERT the results. A giant advantage of per-worker log files is it lets you scale out to multiple compute hosts. On mysql / postgres databases I have certainly seen long running SELECT transactions hold reader locks which starve writers, e.g. ALTER TABLE attempts. A simple COMMIT releases the lock. With sqlite, I think you need to disconnect / reconnect to release? Else the WAL can become much bigger than 4 MiB. cf: reader gaps

Answer (score 3):

**General Approach**

From what I have personally experienced and from what I have read on the Internet, doing concurrent writes to a SQLite database either from multiple threads or multiple processes is problematic and can result in "Database is locked" errors. It seems that your bottleneck is the `compute` function that takes a few seconds to run. So I would compute all the values using multiprocessing in such a fashion that I can do my insert operations as results are computed and returned. The `multiprocessing.pool.map` method will not return until all results have been computed and only then can you start doing your insert operations, which are rather slow using SQLite. Therefore, I suggest using the `multiprocessing.pool.imap` method that will return results as they become available. Unlike the `map` method, `imap` will use a *chunksize* value of 1 if no value for this is passed. For large iterables, this is not efficient. I have included code below that can be used to compute a "suitable" chunksize. Read the comments in the code.

**Use a Context Manager Consistently**

In function `write_result` you are using the connection as a context manager, which is a good practice as it will result in a commit being performed automatically if no exception is raised in the block or a rollback being performed otherwise. But note that the connection context manager as implemented in SQLite does not close the connection upon termination of the block. That is as it should be because you might have subsequent CRUD operations you wish to perform and it does not make sense to close the connection only to have to recreate one.

Still, there are times where it would be desirable for the connection to be automatically closed when the context manager block exits, either normally or with an exception. Such a case is your `reset` function, which is currently not using any context manager. We can implement our own context manager that creates and closes a connection automatically:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_connection(db):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        yield conn
        conn.commit() # if no execption
    except Exception:
        conn.rollback() # if we have an exception
        raise
    finally:
        conn.close() # always close the connection
```

Now function `reset` becomes:

```py
def reset(file):
    with get_connection(file) as con:
        con.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results")
        con.execute("CREATE TABLE results(input UNIQUE, output)")
```

Note that I have added the `IF EXISTS` clause to the `DROP TABLE` command so that it will not raise an exception if the table does not exist.

**Command Line Arguments**

I would suggest that to make running this script more user friendly (so it does not have to be modified for each run) you modify it to take command line arguments that will determine its behavior. For example:

```None
python my_program.py --create
```

This would result in initializing an empty database by calling the `reset` function. Or:

```None
python my_program.py --run 1000 1999
```

This would call the `compute` function for the values in the range 1000 - 1999.

**Other Observations**

If you start with an empty database and from that point do runs specifying ranges that do not overlap, there is no reason why there should be attempts to insert duplicate rows. Therefore, the test you make in `already_present` is just a waste of time. I would prefer to modify `write_result` to catch a potential `sqlite3.IntegrityError` exception that would occur if you ever did try to insert a row that already existed. But better yet might be to do an initial query to the count of rows that already exist where the `input` column contains a value in the range of the passed arguments. If that count is not 0, clearly there is a user error in specifying a non-overlapping range. You might then wish to support the following command:

```py
python my_program.py --query
```

This would print the `max(input)` value from the database. Also:

1. Your code as published would not run because in function `write_result` variable `results` was undefined.
2. My preference is to name constants such as `db` in upper case (`DB`).
3. You have `db` defined at global scope and you use this value to pass to function `reset`. But in other functions the global `db` is accessed directly. This is inconsistent. Decide whether all functions will use a global definition of `db` or you will pass `db` to the functions that need the database name. If you go the latter route, then remove `db` from global scope.
4. You wanted each process to have its own connection so using the *initializer* argument to the `Pool` initializer is appropriate. But instead of just assigning the passed connection to a global `con` variable, you made it an attribute of a function (which is also at global scope so it does work). I find this a confusing choice.

**Example of How I would Do the Multiprocessing**

In the code below I have not incorporated the command line processing I have suggested; I leave that as an exercise for you if you are interested in doing this:

```py
import sqlite3
import multiprocessing
from contextlib import contextmanager

# Use upper case for "constants":
RESET_DB = True  # set to False to continue earlier run
DB = 'results.db'

@contextmanager
def get_connection():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)
        yield conn
        conn.commit() # if no execption
    except Exception:
        conn.rollback() # if we have an exception
        raise
    finally:
        conn.close() # always close the connecti

def compute(x):
    return 2 * x

def reset():
    with get_connection() as con:
        con.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results")
        con.execute("CREATE TABLE results(input UNIQUE, output)")

def write_result(con, param, result):
    # This is using variable con as the standard SQLite context manager,
    # so a commit will be done (but no close) on the connection:
    with con:
        try:
            con.execute("INSERT INTO results VALUES (?, ?)", (param, result)) #  error
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            # Row already exists:
            pass

def main():
    def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
        """This calculates "suitable" chunksize value much in the same way
        that the map function calculates it if you specify chunksize=None."""

        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize


    if RESET_DB:
        reset()

    range_start = 0
    range_end = 999
    iterable = range(range_start, range_end + 1)
    # Number of tasks to be submitted:
    iterable_size = range_end - range_start + 1

    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    # Compute a chunksize
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size)

    with get_connection() as con, \
    multiprocessing.Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        for param, result in enumerate(
            pool.imap(compute, iterable, chunksize=chunksize),
            start=range_start
            ):
            write_result(con, param, result)

# For cross-platform compatibility:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @ga325, this seems like helpful and useful advice. I recommend you adopt it. Personally I tend to access sqlite via [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core), but meh, whatever, there are many paths to success. On items (3) & (4), I will often find that sufficient motivation to put my functions within a `class`, just so self.db and self.con are readily available to all. You might prefer to grab / close() the `con` _within_ the `for` loop so you hold a lock just briefly and immediately release it. Compare and see! [Let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) how it goes.

Comment: This sounds good, but I would like to see a context manager for the SQLite connection too. Alternatively, a finally clause could be used since we already have try blocks.

Comment: @Kate I have updated the answer to show how we can create a custom context manager that will do what the standard connection context manager does but also automatically close the connection when the block exists. See the section **Use a Context Manager Consistently**.